# Apply function with 3 parameters to each row of a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, apply, multiple-arguments

I am trying to apply a function to every row of a dataframe in R. I have already gone through several answers in Stack Overflow but they are not working.

Basically I have a dataframe of latitude and longitude information. The function, convertLngs2, takes in 3 inputs --> the column of longitude information from the dataframe, a source longitude and a destination longitude. If the difference between the source and destination longitude is greater than 180 degrees, all negative values in the longitude column need to be increased by 360 degrees.

```
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

# Source
latWaterloo <- 43.46687 
lngWaterloo <- -80.52464

# Destination
latTaiwan <- 23.5983
lngTaiwan <- 120.8354


convertLngs2 <- function(lonn, srcLng, sonLng) {
  diffr <- abs(srcLng) + abs(sonLng)
  if (diffr > 180) {
    if (lonn<0) {
      lonn <- lonn + 360
    } else {
      lonn <- lonn
    } 
  } else {
    lonn <- lonn
  } 
}


geo_lines <- gcIntermediate(c(lngWaterloo, latWaterloo), c(lngTaiwan, latTaiwan), n=100, addStartEnd=T, sp=F)
geo_lines <- data.frame(geo_lines)

geo_lines2 <- geo_lines %>% mutate(lon=sapply(lon, convertLngs2(lon, lngWaterloo, lngTaiwan)))

geo_lines3 <- geo_lines %>% mutate(lon=convertLngs2(lon, lngWaterloo, lngTaiwan))

geo_lines4 <- geo_lines %>% mutate(lon=lapply(lon, convertLngs2(lon, lngWaterloo, lngTaiwan)))

geo_lines5 <- geo_lines %>% mutate(lon=apply(lon, 1, convertLngs2(lon, lngWaterloo, lngTaiwan)))
```

I need to keep the parameters of srcLng and sonLng in the function. I have tried sapply, lapply and apply but all of them give the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'convertLngs2(lon, lngWaterloo, lngTaiwan)' is not a function, character or symbol.
In addition: Warning message:
In if (lonn < 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What changes are required for the code to work? Thanks!

Comment: You seem not to return anything. Try adding `lonn` outside the if statements. I cannot test as I cannot donwload these packages(not my field).

Comment: If you use `ifelse` instead of `if ... else`, your function will be vectorized, so you don't need to iterate with `*apply` at all. And the one you're looking for it `mapply` or `Map`.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you, both the ifelse and mapply worked!